# Open link in Popup Window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, popup, modal-dialog

I'm trying to load a href into a popup window of specific dimensions which also centers in the screen.

Here is my source:

```
<li>
    <a class="sprite_stumbleupon" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://www.your_web_page_url" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(545, 433)"></a>
</li>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
function windowpop(url, width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    //Open the window.
    window.open(url, "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
}
```

This seems to return a 404 error when tested. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: You haven't sent the `url` parameter to the `windowpop` function.

Comment: `function windowpop(url, width, height)` The function is expecting you to return a URL but you're only returning width and height.

Comment: This may be closed for a good reason, but I found it crazy helpful. I didn't know about any of those extra parameters to window.open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`function windowpop(url, width, height)` The function requires a URL to be returned to it.

`onclick="return windowpop(545, 433)"` You're only returning the `width` and `height`.

Try returning the URL using `this.href`:

```
onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 545, 433)"
```

```html
<script>
function windowpop(url, width, height) {
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
    window.open(url, "", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just a note, I was using this method, and works fine if you do not allow popups on your browser, however, if you do, it will open the popup twice. I solved it by adding event.preventDefault(); on click of the link, and remove the return from the start of windowpop().