# Open link in Popup Window with Javascript ( event.preventDefault(); )

Tags: javascript, html, popup

THis question was answered earlier, and closed here:
[Open link in Popup Window with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182915/open-link-in-popup-window-with-javascript)

But if you scrol down, you will see this comment:

Just a note, I was using this method, and works fine if you do not allow popups on your browser, however, if you do, it will open the popup twice. I solved it by adding event.preventDefault(); on click of the link, and remove the return from the start of windowpop(). –  madaaah Oct 18 '13 at 18:13

I am having this same problem of twice popup, and did not understand how to use event.preventDefault();

```
function windowpop(url, width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    //Open the window.
    window.open(url, "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
}


<li>
    <a class="sprite_stumbleupon" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://www.your_web_page_url" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 545, 433)"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: At the end of the function, add `return false;`. This will implicitly do `preventDefault()` because the inline handler is returning the return value of the function. Alternatively don't use an inline click handler.

Comment: i added the return false; after windows.open line, no success!