# Django Custom Admin Popup

Tags: popup, django-admin

I need to resend an email to a user in case the user requests it, from the back-end.
I want to handle the logic in a separate template than the one I trigger the view from.
I figured using a Pop-up would be the best approach for this, but Django doesn't seem to provide any documentation on this.

I have checked out a few posts similar to what I am looking for like, http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/ , but they are either too old or too different.

I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I rolled my own version using guidelines from this links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182915/open-link-in-popup-window-with-javascript. I hope somebody else finds it helpful.

Comment: More edits here; http://jsfiddle.net/tsiiiboho/9YTr2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled my own version using guidelines from this links, [Open link in Popup Window with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182915/open-link-in-popup-window-with-javascript). I hope somebody else finds it helpful.