# Open leaflet marker popup-link in a new window

Tags: popup, leaflet

I have a problem using links in leaflet marker popups:
My loop assigns a link to every popup so I can open the specific source by clicking the popup

```js
var link = "<a href=\""+"http://localhost/Webseite_Daten/diagramm_erstellen.php?diagramm=" +nr+"\""+">Grafik erstellen</a>";
L.marker([lat,lon], {icon: marker}).bindPopup(link).addTo(map);
```

It´s possible to open the link which appears in the popup, but I need to open it in a new (popup) window (simulate the windows-function of right-mouse-click: "open in new tab")

How can I realize this issue?

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, add the target="_blank" attribute to the **a href=""...**-tag:

```
var link = "<a href=\""+"http://localhost/Webseite_Daten/diagramm_erstellen.php?diagramm=" +nr+"\""+" target=\"_blank\">Grafik erstellen</a>";
L.marker([lat,lon], {icon: marker}).bindPopup(link).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Is it also possible to open a popup window instead of a new tab?

Comment: you should look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182915/open-link-in-popup-window-with-javascript .
by addin the onclick="return windowpop()" argument to your link you should be able to do this.
Please give me an upvote, if you liked my answer before. thx